# python - struggling with designing this

Tags: python

I had a quiz in class today and I failed it miserably, the quiz is below. 
Can someone help explain this to me.

1. Add a method `open()` to Link that will disconnect it from the Link ‘just to its left’ thus opening the necklace while keeping the chain unbroken to the right. For example, if grasping necklace at `link1`, then calling `link1.open()` would disconnect `link3` from `link1` but leave one still holding the chain from `link1` to `link3` connected.

**this is what I currently have:**

```
class Diamond(object):
    def __str__(self):
        return "Diamond"

class Ruby(object):
    def __str__(self):
        return "Ruby"

class Visitor:
    def __str__(self):
        return self.__class__.__name__

class Link(object):
    def __init__(self, index, jewel = None):
        self.jewel = jewel
        self.index = index

    def connectTo(self, link):
        self.nextLink = link

    def __next__(self):
        return self.nextLink or None

    def attach(self, jewel):
        if not self.jewel:
            self.jewel = jewel

    def detatch(self):
        stone = self.jewel
        self.jewel = None
        return stone

    def open(self):
        pass

    def __str__(self):
        return "link%d" % (self.index)

class Necklace(object):
    def __init__(self, base):
        self.base = base

    def describe(self):
        link = self.base
        while True:
            print link, "with", link.jewel, "attatched to", link.nextLink, "with", link.nextLink.jewel
            link = link.nextLink
            if link == self.base:
                break

    def getJewel(self):
        link = self.base
        while True:
            link = link
            if isinstance(link.jewel, Diamond):
                print "a", link.detatch()
                break
            link = link.nextLink
            if link == self.base:
                print "nothing..."
                break

    def acceptVisitor(self, visitor):
        visitor.visit(self)

class DiamondThief(object, Visitor):
    def __init__(self, base):
        self.base = base
        self.jewel = self.base.jewel

    def visit(self, necklace):
        necklace.getJewel()

    def searchForDiamond(self):
        self.visit(myNecklace)

link1 = Link(1, Ruby())
link2 = Link(2, Diamond())
link3 = Link(3, Ruby())
link1.connectTo(link2)
link2.connectTo(link3)
link3.connectTo(link1)
myNecklace = Necklace(link1)
myNecklace.describe()

print "Uh on here comes a thief..."
thief = DiamondThief(link1)
print "Oh no he took "
thief.searchForDiamond()
myNecklace.describe()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "explain this to me"??

Comment: I have no idea how to do this, like I get what is being asked but I couldn't for the life of me design it, and I'm trying right now to do it on my own in order to understand it but I can't figure it out at all. Like what would the classes and functions look like

Comment: @user1758231 In the present form, your question is too broad. I suspect you won't learn designing a similar problem if one of us posts the solution for this one. You can at least come up with your understanding of the problem by writing the signatures of the classes and the interactions between them.

Comment: I posted what I currently have and what I'm trying to work on

Comment: For part 1, was there a diagram of the necklace you were supposed to make? The wording seems to be suggesting that.

Comment: yeah link1 should have a ruby, link2 a diamond, link3 a ruby that's it, just shows what the necklace should look like

Answer (score 1):

Let's see **what functions do we need in each class**?

1. `Link`

   - Variables

     - `name` (just maybe)
     - `linked_to` or `nextlink`
     - `jewel`
   - Methods

     - `connectTo(self,link)`
     - `attach(self,jewel)`
     - `detach(self)`
     - `open(self)`
     - `get_next(self)`
2. `Necklace` (not in code below, make it on your own)

   - Variables

     - `connections`
   - Methods

     - `__next__(self)` or `next_link(self)`
3. `DiamondThief`

   - Variables

     - `link`
     - `diamond`
   - Methods

     - `getDiamond(self)`
     - `search(self)`
4. `Jewels` like `Diamond` or `Ruby`

   - No variables or methods

See this code, I have also added the DiamondThief class...

```
class Necklace:
    '''My version of necklace'''
    def __init__(self, link):
        self.first = link
        self.current_link = link
    def next(self):
        self.current_link = self.current_link.get_next()
        if self.current_link == self.first:
            raise StopIteration
        return self.current_link
    def __iter__(self):
        return self

class Link(object):
    """A link of a necklace"""
    def __init__(self, name, jewel=None):
        self.name = name
        self.linkedTo = None
        self.jewel = None
        if jewel != None:
            self.attach(jewel)

    def connectTo(self, link):
        '''Connect to link'''
        if isinstance(link,Link):
            self.linkedTo = link
        else:
            raise TypeError

    def attach(self, jewel):
        '''Attach jewel'''
        if self.jewel == None:
            self.jewel = jewel
        else:
            msg = 'There is already a %s attached' % jewel.__class__.__name__
            raise AttributeError(msg)

    def detach(self):
        '''Detach jewel'''
        if self.jewel != None: # 
            je = self.jewel
            self.jewel = None
            return j
        else:
            msg = 'There is nothing to detach'
            raise AttributeError(msg)

    def __str__(self):
        if self.linkedTo != None:
            return "%s(%s) => %s" % \
                   (self.name,self.jewel.__class__.__name__, self.linkedTo.name)
        else:
            return "%s(%s) => %s" % \
                   (self.name,self.jewel.__class__.__name__,None)

    def get_next(self):
        '''Get the next chain'''
        return self.linkedTo

class Diamond(object):
    pass

class Ruby(object):
    pass

class DiamondThief:
    def __init__(self, necklace):
        self.necklace = necklace
        self.diamond = None

    def search(self):
        '''Go link by link to find the Diamond'''
        if self.diamond != None:
            print 'Have a diamond already'
            return 
        first = self.necklace.first
        link = first
        for link in self.necklace: # loop till
            if isinstance(link.jewel, Diamond): # diamond is found
                self.diamond = link.jewel
                link.jewel = None
                print 'Found Diamond'
                break

    def getDiamond(self):
        if self.diamond != None:
            return self.diamond
        else:
            return None

def main():
    # create
    l1 = Link('1',Diamond())
    l2 = Link('2',Ruby())
    l3 = Link('3', Ruby())
    l1.connectTo(l2)
    l2.connectTo(l3)
    l3.connectTo(l1)
    i = DiamondThief()
    try:
        l2.attach(Ruby())
    except AttributeError,e:
        print e
    print l1
    print l2
    print l3
    print '-'*16
    i.search()
    print l1
    print l2
    print l3
main()
```

Comment: this is great but we were suppose to use the visitor pattern in the thief class thats what i'm trying to do now

Comment: Why do you want the visitor??

Answer (score 0):

Part 1 simply asks you to use the methods described on the `Link` class to build a specified necklace:

```
link1 = Link()
link1.attach(Ruby())
link2 = Link()
link2.attach(Diamond())
link3 = Link()
link3.attach(Ruby())

link1.connectTo(link2)
link2.connectTo(link3)
link3.connectTo(link1)

myNecklace = link1
```

Part 2 requires an implementation of the Link and DiamondThief classes.

Here's how I'd implement `Link`, as a doubly linked list. You don't really need the second link to implement the basic methods we need to do in this part, but adding `open` in part 3 will be much easier if we have references to both the left and the right neighbor links.

```
class Link(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize an empty link."""
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.jewel = None

    def connectTo(self, other):
        """Connect another link to the right of this one."""
        if self.right or other.left:
            raise ValueError("Links already have connections")
        self.right = other
        other.left = self

    def attach(self, jewel):
        """Add a jewel to this link."""
        if self.jewel:
            raise ValueError("Link already has a jewel attached")
        self.jewel = jewel

    def detatch(self):
        """Remove and return the jewel attached to this link."
        jewel = self.jewel
        self.jewel = None
        return jewel
```

Here's my implementation of the `DiamondThief` visitor. It's main method is `visit` which recursively visits subsequent `Link` instances until a diamond has been found or it loops (or runs off the end of an open necklace). You could do the same thing with a `while` loop instead of recursion, but this seemed simpler. Note that the `or` expression in the recursive call means that if `first` is None (which it will be by default) then `link` will be passed as `first`.

```
class DiamondThief(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize a DiamondThief"""
        self.diamond = None

    def visit(self, link, first=None):
        """Recursively visit a necklace, searching for a Diamond to steal."""
        if link == first: # looped
            return
        if isinstance(link.jewel, Diamond): # diamond found
            self.diamond = link.detatch()
            return
        if link.right is not None: # not at an open end
            self.visit(link.right, first or link)

    def getDiamond(self):
        return self.diamond
```

Part 3 asks you to add an `open` method to the `Link` class. Since `Link` is doubly linked, it's easy to break the list to the left of the current position. If you'd implemented it as a singly linked list, you'd have to scan over the whole necklace (going from each link to its right neighbor) until you found the one that linked back to the first instance. It wouldn't work at all on a necklace that didn't form a loop.

Anyway, here's the simple implementation:

```
def open(self):
    """Disconnect this link from it's left neighbor."""
    if self.left is None:
        raise ValueError("Link is not connected on the left")
    self.left.right = None
    self.left = None
```